# MongoDB search results for values only matching array items

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Folks,

I am able to search MongoDB Collection for any value in an array:

```
var searchArray = ['foo','bar'];
```

with the following query:

```
var query = {
    widgets: {
        '$in': searchArray
    }
};
```

The result will be Objects that have `widgets` that match either `foo` or `bar`.

What should the MongoDB query look like to search for `widgets` that are `foo` and `bar` and nothing else.  In other words, only widgets that have `foo` and `bar` in them will be returned.  If there is a [`foo`,`bar,`baz`] it will be skipped.  If there is only a ['foo'], it will be skipped as well.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:
This seems to work:

```
var query = {
    widgets: {
        '$all': searchArray
    }
};
```

Anything wrong with using `$all` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your query object as a straight-up match:

```js
var searchArray = ['foo','bar'];
var query = {
    widgets: searchArray
};
```

Comment: why not use `$all` ? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

Comment: @Cmag Because  `$all` would also match `widgets: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`.